# How to get all members of a voice-channel with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have the problem, if I will get all members as an object of Meber of a specific Voice-channel. I only get a empty list back.

This is my Code:

```py
@bot.command(name='random')
async def nine_nine(ctx, amount_of_groups: int):
    this_guild = ctx.guild
    sender = ctx.message.author
    #Es wird geschaut, in welchem Channel sich der Schreiber befindet
    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        print(voice_channel)
    except AttributeError:
        await ctx.send("Du bist in keinem Voice-Channel")
        return
    #Alle anderen Mitglieder aus dem Kanal werden ermittelt und in eine Liste geschrieben
    this_category = voice_channel.category

    member_list = voice_channel.members # <-- This only returns an empty List

    print(member_list)
    print(this_category)
    #Die Mitglieder werden gemischt
    random.shuffle(member_list)
    #Die Mitglieder werden in gleichgroße Gruppen aufgeteilt
    avg = len(member_list) / float(amount_of_groups)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(member_list):
        out.append(member_list[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg
    print(out)
    for group in range(0, amount_of_groups):
        new_channel = await this_guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'Gruppe{group+1}', category=this_category)
        for member in range(len(out[group])):
            try:
                await out[group][member].move_to(new_channel)
            except:
                print("F")
            print(out[group][member])
```

How can I fix this Problem?

Comment: `member_list = voice_channel.members` have you verified you have Member Intents on your Discord Developer API page enabled (where you initially got the bot token)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable `Intents.members` like this before `bot = ...` :

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

and update the `bot = ..` to include the argument `intents=intents`.

Also you have to enable member intents in your application site in discord ([go here](https://discord.com/developers/applications), click on your bot, click on `bot` at the sidebar and enable them.):
[image: Enable member intents]

References:

[discord.Intents.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members)

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled the intents? If you didn't, go to discord.com/developers/dashboard, select your bot and enable intents. After that enable intents in your code with:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.Member = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="yourprefix", intents=intents)
```