# (discordrb)How to get all members in a specific voice channel in discordrb?

Tags: ruby, discord

I know there're tons of similar questions with discord.py but could anyone please tell me how to get all members in a specific voice channel using discordrb?

The code I wrote is like below.

```rb
require 'discordrb'
require 'dotenv/load'

bot = Discordrb::Commands::CommandBot.new token: "#{ENV['TOKEN']}", prefix: '!'

bot.command(:test) do |event|
  channel = event.user.voice_channel
  server = event.user.server
  current_channel = Discordrb::Channel.new({'id' => channel.id}, bot, server)
  bot.voice_connect(current_channel)
  current_channel.users
end

bot.run
```

with the code above I could get only an empty array.
I thought this question([python - How to get all members of a voice-channel with discord.py - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296197/how-to-get-all-members-of-a-voice-channel-with-discord-py)) seemed same as my situation so I tried enabling intent.
I changed discord website's bot at the sidebar and enable it and changed my code as below.

```rb
require 'discordrb'
require 'dotenv/load'

bot = Discordrb::Commands::CommandBot.new token: "#{ENV['TOKEN']}", prefix: '!', intents: [:server_members]

bot.command(:test) do |event|
  channel = event.user.voice_channel
  server = event.user.server
  current_channel = Discordrb::Channel.new({'id' => channel.id}, bot, server)
  bot.voice_connect(current_channel)
  current_channel.users
end

bot.command(:foo) do |event|
  event.send_message "Foo"
end

bot.run
```

What happened was both `!test`& `!foo` commands didn't work.
I mean, there's no error but doesn't display anything.

Please give me advice on what I can do to work this code as I intended! Thanks,